# R function for testing signifiant differences between variables multiple models

Tags: r

I have two probit models:

```
probit2 <- glm(DataBreach ~ CyberCommittee + CyberOA + CyberJobs + CyberEducation + CyberAchievements, data = df27, family = binomial(link = 'probit'))
probit2m <- margins(probit2)

probit2.1 <- glm(DataBreach ~ CyberOA + CyberJobs + CyberEducation + CyberAchievements, data = df27, family = binomial(link = 'probit'))
probit2.1m <- margins(probit2.1)
```

And those models have the following results:

```
                       MODEL 2                   MODEL 2.1
CyberCommittee         -0.248 ***   (0.006)                          
CyberAchievements      -0.026 ***   (0.001)      -0.037 ***   (0.001)
CyberEducation         -0.040 ***   (0.003)      -0.057 ***   (0.003) 
CyberJobs              -0.025 ***   (0.002)      -0.038 ***   (0.002)
CyberOA                -0.021 ***   (0.001)      -0.029 ***   (0.001)
```

I am not really familiar with Z-test and things like that. But I want to know how I can test if there is a significant difference between the coefficients that are used in both models. So, not the difference between the models, but the difference between every single coefficient.

Comment: Not sure how you could tackle this as one model has more predictor variables. Maybe consider the confidence intervl for each predictor and check whether one lies in the interval of the other.

Answer (score 0):

One neat trick is to “stack” datasets and use interactions to estimate distinct coefficients. Then, you can use the delta method (e.g., `marginaleffects::deltamethod`) to run hypothesis tests.

First, we show that a single model can reproduce the coefficients of two separate models:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(modelsummary)

dat1 <- transform(iris[1:75,], dataset = "A") 
dat2 <- transform(iris[76:150,], dataset = "B")
dat <- rbind(dat1, dat2)

mod1 <- lm(
    Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,
    data = subset(dat, dataset == "A"))
mod2 <- lm(
    Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length,
    data = subset(dat, dataset == "B"))
mod3 <- lm(
    Sepal.Length ~ dataset + 
                   as.numeric(dataset == "A") : Sepal.Width +
                   as.numeric(dataset == "B") : (Sepal.Width + Petal.Length), 
    data = dat)

modelsummary(list(mod1, mod2, mod3), gof_map = NA)
```

|  | (1) | (2) | (3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 5.987 | 2.249 | 5.987 |
|  | (0.499) | (0.382) | (0.405) |
| Sepal.Width | -0.201 | 0.289 |  |
|  | (0.154) | (0.149) |  |
| Petal.Length |  | 0.638 |  |
|  |  | (0.058) |  |
| datasetB |  |  | -3.738 |
|  |  |  | (0.686) |
| as.numeric(dataset == “A”) × Sepal.Width |  |  | -0.201 |
|  |  |  | (0.125) |
| Sepal.Width × as.numeric(dataset == “B”) |  |  | 0.289 |
|  |  |  | (0.217) |
| as.numeric(dataset == “B”) × Petal.Length |  |  | 0.638 |
|  |  |  | (0.084) |

Then, we conduct hypothesis tests to compare the 3rd and 4th coefficients:

```r
deltamethod(mod3, "b3 = b4")
```

```
     term   estimate std.error statistic    p.value   conf.low     conf.high
1 b3 = b4 -0.4901944 0.2499289 -1.961335 0.04983992 -0.9800461 -0.0003427295
```